# select polygon loaded from kml having its title

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to select a polygon loaded from kml (in js) from its title but I do not know how (I found only from js variable if manually defined the single polygon). Is this possible?
If not, what is the best way to "copy" a selected polygon (define a new polygon take the data from the selected one) on a double click event (for example for show it with a different style) and delete the loaded kml (with hundreds of polygons)?

Thanks for any reply and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not found a way to point directly the polygon loaded by kml for title but thanks to [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=VoterDistricts_address.xml) using geoxml3 that parse, show kml and permit "after parse" operations and with I reached the goal, although with a lot of code for a few small operations. Thanks to the people that worked on them.